# Auslander-Buchsbaum formula without minimal/finite resolutions

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Does anybody know a proof of Auslander-Buchsbaum's formula that uses only projective/injective/flat resolutions and homological functors Ext and Hom without using minimal/finite resolutions?

Comment: Since the formula assumes that projective dimension is finite, am not sure how one will avoid a finite resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Maurice Auslander Memorial Workshop notes](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/birep/meetings/auslander2014/Notes/Becker.pdf) you find a classical proof of the Auslander-Buchsbaum formula which involves minimal projective resolutions in Lemma 2.2 only, where it could be made explicit without much effort, alongside a 'modern language' proof using derived categories. Maybe you find it useful.

Comment: I read the definition of a syzygy and now I more or less know that it's a free resolution. But how is it constructed? I mean does any R-module has a syzygy? And if yes, is it always finite?

Answer (score 0):

Auslander-Buchsbaum formula is a corollary of the much more general isomorphism

$$\mathrm{Ext}_A^n(k,M)=\bigoplus_{i-j=n}\mathrm{Ext}_A^i(k,A)\otimes_k\mathrm{Tor}_{-j}^A(k,M) $$
which is valid for not necessarily finite modules $M$ (of finite projective dimension). Therefore minimal resolutions are not necessary.

You may find a proof of this (in fact a more general) result in Strooker, *Homological Questions in Local Algebra*, p. 117.